# Binding Angular Service object to Controller Scope and updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an `EmployeeService` that I inject into an `EmployeeController`.  The `EmployeeService` contains an object.

I bind Service object into Controller Scope:

```
app.controller('EmployeeController', function($scope, EmployeeService) {
    $scope.employee = EmployeeService.getEmployee();
}
```

HTML template displays the name of the Employee:

```
{{employee.name}}
```

If I manipulate the employee object in the `EmployeeService` ... i.e. `EmployeeService.getEmployee().name = 'new name'`, the template displays the new name.

However, if I **replace** the employee object in the `EmployeeService` ... i.e. `EmployeeService.setEmployee({name: 'new name'})` the template does not display the new name.

Why is replacing the Service object not reflected in the template?

I have the following Plunk that demonstrates this: http://plnkr.co/edit/k7oKd1VgsBvMGvVdP5kM?p=preview

In my Plunk, Employee Controller/Service works and Manager Controller/Service does not.

If anyone could help me understand what is going on I would really appreciate it.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/s4jdqXsxd6G1S5uUqjh6?p=preview other way of updating manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the controller to watch for changes to the manager.

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return ManagerService.getManager();//<--when this changes
  }, function(newManager) { //<-- run this function
    $scope.manager = ManagerService.getManager();
  });
```

Here is an updated Plunkr with one way to do it:
http://plnkr.co/edit/YE72JcxDSFqfZLH32ERy?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the way angular watches the original object. If you declare `{{employee.name}}` angular starts watching the object reference for changes.
As you said: changes to `EmployeeService.getEmployee().name` are correctly noticed and reflected in the view.

But `EmployeeService.setEmployee({name: 'new name'})` replaces the watched object with a new object while angular still watches the original one. Hence your change is not recognized by angular and the view does not update.

Comment: Okay ... that makes sense.  The unfortunate problem I have is that this is a simple example I put together and our enterprise app ... Restangular pulls down a big complex object, and I need to put it into a Service and bind it to Controller Scope.  Any ideas?

Comment: Only add this object to the scope once it is retrieved. `$scope.employee = ...` or copy the properties to the watched object. And please accept this answer if it solved your original question to help others...